Get the caller function object when it's a static method
I thought I knew a bit of Python, but then I stumped on this (a distilled form follows):
class A:

    @staticmethod
    def f():
        print('some code here to report exactly 
               who called A.f()')

class B:

    @staticmethod
    def f():
        A.f()

class C:

    @staticmethod
    def f():
        A.f()

B.f() # I want this to print 'B.f'
C.f() # I want this to print 'C.f'


Note: compared to How can I get the address of the caller function?, this question describes a much more difficult situation (in my opinion). In fact, the referred question is easily solvable using an iteration over globals (see below).
Here's what I tried:

If I use the inspect module I get access to the the caller function's name as a str (not the caller function's object itself), and so I can't use the __qualname__.

If I try to iterate over the globals to see which global object has a method named 'f' I get two answers with no way to decide between the two.

I thought that an attribute 'cls' should be among the locals, just like 'self' would be if these were regular functions (not static methods), and if so I could get to the class by inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals['cls'], but 'cls' is not there.


Any ideas?
UPD1: I keep digging and so far approach 1) seems the most promising: as soon as I get hold of the caller function object (not just the name, but the function itself) I'm all set. However, I don't see a way to do that in the setup above. One way around this would be to add an argument to A.f() and make all caller functions pass a copy of themselves: A.f(caller_func = Caller_Class.f). But it seems like double accounting. So, any ideas are still appreciated.

If you want X.f() to print X (any value depending on the class), it is by definition not a static method. It would be a class method.

I'm confused about why you even need this since you already know you are inside B when you call the method

@RodrigoRodrigues Makes sense: the static method should be agnostic about the class. But I don't need the class, I just need the class name: my A.f() needs to report which function called it, and the caller can be a global function, a class function, a class method or a static method. The function's name can be the same, in principle, in all these cases. This means that Python somehow distinguishes them. An obvious guess is that it keeps track of where they come from (i.e. knows the function's parent: a class or 'global'). So the question is: can one get access to this info?

@roganjosh A.f() is part of some intricate debug logging code in a system with lots of recursion, and so I want it to be able to report the full recursion branch whenever called. In the example above there's just one leg of that branch shown, to simplify the question.

If this is for debug logging, then why do you need access o the function object instead of the function name as a string?

@wim I need the name of the parent class, and in method 1) i can get that using func. __qualname__

It's still not clear to me why you want the function object itself and can't use the string from qualname.

You were on the right track with your point 1. in your question: with inspect, you can get caller function's name as a str (which is useless to get the qualified name), but you ignored that the frame object also has the attribute f_code, which is of type codeobject and that recently in python 3.11 got the attribute co_qualname, exactly the fully qualified function name at the given frame.
So, as simple as:
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def f():
        print(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_qualname) 

B.f() # prints B.f
C.f() # prints C.f

You can see more details here.

Oh, wow! I'm on 3.9, maybe that's why I missed it. That's exactly what I was looking for :) Enormous Thank You!

Your third point describes a class method, not a static method.
class C:
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        print(cls)

c1 = C()
c2 = C()

# All three bind the class C to the cls parameter.
c1.foo()
c2.foo()
C.foo()

Static methods have little to do with the class itself, other than binding what is essentially an ordinary function to a class attribute. The static method, when called, receives no additional arguments.

You are right. And 3) solves the class method case. However, my original question is about static methods.
